# Angular 5 custom directive input attribute values undefined

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to pass a value to the directive's custom attribute, but when I try to log it it says it is undefined.

This is my component.html:

```
<div appRadialMenu [step]="4"></div>
```

This is my directive.ts:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// jQuery
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appRadialMenu]'
})
export class RadialMenuDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() step;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
      $(elRef.nativeElement).click(function () {
          console.log(this.step);
      }
  }
  ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.step);
  }
}
```

**Edit**: I also tried using

```
@Input('step') step;
```

**Edit 2**: Thank you guys, it worked and I made the following changes:

I changed the click event binding and I moved it to the ngOnInit, also I changed the selector

```
selector: 'appRadialMenu'
// ......
@Input('step') step;

constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
    $(this.elRef.nativeElement).click(() => {
        console.log(this.step);
    });
}
```

component.html:

```
<appRadialMenu [step]="4"></appRadialMenu>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Use an arrow function as the callback: `.click(() => { ... })`. More importantly, avoid using jQuery for event binding.

Comment: `@Input('step') step;` is the correct one, also correct the selector, should be: 
 `selector: 'appRadialMenu'` and to use it: `<appRadialMenu [step]="4"></appRadialMenu>`, and accessing the `step` in the constructor is wrong, use `ngOnInit` instead, or `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Do not answer your question in the question. Feel free to write an answer yourself -- you can even accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an alias for the input property so that you don't have to use another property named `steps` on the Directive.

Apart from that, you will get the changed `steps` count in your `ngOnChanges`. So use that instead of `ngOnInit`.

This should be your directive.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appRadialMenu]'
})
export class RadialMenuDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input('appRadialMenu') step;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
      console.log('Got steps as: ', this.step);
  }

}
```

Since you'll be using the `appRadialMenu` directive with an attribute binding syntax, it should be assigned a property that will be defined on your Component class.

Here's how you can use it in your Component Template:

```
<div [appRadialMenu]="steps"></div>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-disable-directive?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradial-menu.directive.ts) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values to directive in multiple ways using `@Input()` i.e.

1. You can directly pass some value to `directive` i.e. `[MyDirective]="someValue"`
2. You can create another input variable in `directive` to accept another value i.e. `@Input('otherValue') otherValue: number`

**Html**

```
<div [MyDirective]="someValue" [otherValue]="20">
     {{someValue | number: '1.0-0'}}
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[MyDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective implements OnChanges {

  @Input('MyDirective') value: number
  @Input('otherValue') otherValue: number
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.value)
    console.log(this.otherValue)
  }
}
```

**Note:** You can pass any number of variables to directive using `@Input()`.